# lets-encrypt gui old fashioned gui style

Tags: python, user-interface, lets-encrypt

Does anyone know how the `letsencrypt` gui was written? It's in the old 90's that is very boxy and has a lot of blue and shadowing like the boxes are actually 3D.

Comment: Why is this tagged with python?

Comment: lets-encrypt was written strictly in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably using Ncurses.

[image]

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: No idea, never tried. But I would start this way : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html